# How do I uninstall SBT in OS X?

Tags: macos, sbt, uninstallation

I want to remove SBT (Simple Build Tool) from my Mac. How do I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends how you installed it. If it has been done through homebrew you should just run in the command line:

```
$ brew uninstall sbt
```

The other solution is to manually delete the launcher script

```
$ which sbt
/Users/bam/bin/sbt
$ rm /Users/bam/bin/sbt
```

Comment: Adding how to also remove the path will be even more helpful. What you have added works fine but user will get an error saying sbt doesn't exist in the given path, you should also add a command which removes it from the path and so end user should get a mesage that command not found

Answer (score 7):

You also need to remove manually sbtopts and sbtopts.default from /usr/local/etc

Answer (score 0):

window uninstall

```
choco uninstall sbt
```

Window Install

```
choco install sbt
```